# How to use write line to print an integer value from another class?

Tags: c#, class, int, call, console.writeline

I'm trying to output a changing integer value in main used and created in multiple other classes. For learning purposes I'm seeing if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do and see what's causing the errors. Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // how do I avoid an identifier error with unit.() if the other class is unit:stats?
        unit.();
        // how can I get the troop value from the unit:stats class?
        Console.WriteLine(troop);
    }
}
public class stats
{
    public int troop;
}
public class unit : stats
{
    public void archer()
    {
        troop = 100;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if it's possible`, Yes, just read docs about basic C#

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an "instance" of your object.  So, in your main:

```
unit myUnit = new unit(); //Create an instance of unit
myUnit.archer(); //Run the method that sets the troop number
Console.WriteLine(myUnit.troop);//Access the troop value from myUnit
```

Comment: @EZI It looks like the OP wants to output a value, not return one.

Comment: OK, not-compilable answer to a not-compilable question... (How do you think `troop = 100;` should work.)

Comment: @EZI Compiles when my code is placed in the provided `Main` (you know...where the question is).

Comment: @EZI `troop` is inherited from `stats`...what are you getting at?